# Linux BASH - Replace multiple occurrences of a char, omitting single occurrence

Tags: string, bash, replace, character

Experts:
this is a bit hard to explain. I need to replace multiple occurrences of a character with some other character (I know this could be accomplished by using sed or tr) the tricky part is that I need to keep single occurrences of the character as they are.

Example, replacing multiple occurrences of "_" with ";":

This is what I have:
**"This_*_*__*_*__*_*___is_a____string"**

This is what I need:
**"This;is_a;string"**

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well with sed you could do below:

```
echo "This___________is_a____string" | sed 's/_\{2,\}/;/g'
```

Output:

```
This;is_a;string
```

The trivial part being the {2,} quantifier which means match any _ 2 or longer, ie. it will leave single _ unchanged.